# Getting value from async task class to another class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1wa.png)

This is my asyncResponse.java

```
 public interface asyncResponse {

    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

This is my trialmenu.java where i want to retrieve my value

```
abstract class trialmenu extends AppCompatActivity implements asyncResponse{
private ImageView logo;
private TextView status;

AsyncStatus asyncTask =new  AsyncStatus();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newmenulayout);

    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglogo);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);

    AsyncStatus.delegate = this;


}



void processFinish(String output) {
    status.setText(output);


}
}
```

This is my AsyncStatus.java, I haven't posted my doInBackground for privacy reasons

```
public class AsyncStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, StringBuilder> {

public static asyncResponse delegate=null;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    delegate.processFinish(result.toString());


}
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize you asyncResponse inside the constructor? make you processFinish public inside your class and @Override is missing from your processFinish

Comment: It should be `@Override public void processFinish(){ ... }`

Comment: You need to annotate the error funtion with  @Override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **register callback** to `AsyncTask` class.

```
 public class AsyncStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, StringBuilder> {

    public asyncResponse delegate=null;

    public void setDelegate(asyncResponse delegate){
            this.delegate=delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        delegate.processFinish(result.toString());


    }
}
```

Do not use a static callback . And you can implement in your calling class by implementing `asyncResponse` or by `Anonymous`. And `processFinish()` implementation has to be **public** with `@Override`
 annotation.

```
abstract class trialmenu extends AppCompatActivity implements asyncResponse {
    private ImageView logo;
    private TextView status;
    AsyncStatus asyncTask = new AsyncStatus();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newmenulayout);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imglogo);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        asyncTask.setDelegete(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        // Callback
    }
}
```

**Suggestion**- Follow [naming convention in java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) to make code more readable.

Comment: Where does the AsyncTask actually executes? I have to send parameters through the AsyncTask. e.g  new AsyncStatus().execute(studID);

Comment: You have to call asyncTask.execute(studID) .

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio instead of trying to override the method your-self try and see if Android Studio will do it for you so I'd copy your old method code, then delete. Go to the interface in which you are implementing, then press Alt+Enter, then you should see "Implement Methods". Once you do that there shouldn't be any conflicting errors with your method, let me know if this works :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your class AsyncStatus and class trialmenu in same package? If not, your AsyncStatus cannot access your trialmenu method, or change method processFinish to public.

Comment: Yes it was in the same package